# Может ли автор удалить свой ответ, который ни у кого не вызвал интереса?

Tags: обсуждение

**Всё-таки отвечать только для себя как-то странно,** хотя и полезно в некоторой степени.

Вот автор задал вопрос, он вызвал у меня **интерес**, поэтому я отвечаю. Более того, я часто отвечаю на **проблемные вопросы**, которые  не кажутся однозначными. Поэтому мне хотелось бы услышать мнение других участников, я рассчитываю на обсуждение, на дискуссию.

**А в ответ — тишина!**  **Автор вопроса** или вообще не читал ответа, или ничего не понял, или он его не удовлетворил.

**От участников форума** тоже реакции никакой: то ли не читали, то ли неинтересно. Аккуратно обходят всю тему стороной.

**Мне жалко ответ,** он выглядит так сиротливо, как брошенный ребенок. Наверное, для окружающих это **информационный мусор** (есть такой новый термин в нашей жизни), а этого нельзя допускать. Поэтому появляется желание  **удалить ответ** в личную папку (другим не нужно, а мне, возможно, пригодится).

Как общество и, главное, модераторы на это смотрят: **можно так сделать**, система не будет против? Вот только не знаю, **какой срок** обозначить: неделю, две недели?

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, что удалять такие сообщение вовсе не стоит!

Во-первых, они отображают особое мнение, которое может быть полезно сотням людей, которые пришли на сайт с помощью поисковой системы и не имеют возможность ни прокомментировать сообщение, ни оценить его.

Во-вторых, мы собираем базу вопросов и ответов на них, а это значит, что сообщения с нулевым рейтингом не менее важны, чем сообщения с большим количеством комментариев или высоким рейтингом.

Comment: Если ответ никого не заинтересовал, то, возможно, он неверен, или низкого качества, а для посетителей форума и для информационной базы нужен качественный материал. Пусть тогда система дает оценку или принимает ответ, если у нее есть к нему интерес. Меня же интересует еще и административное сторона вопроса: можно ли удалять, если вопрос не имеет никаких отметок и комментариев? Система не будет преследовать такие действия?

Comment: @Sharon, будет. На массовое удаление собственных сообщений есть автоматическая тревога о возможном вандализме. Кстати, тоже не считаю нужным что-то удалять. Если бы ответ был неверным, на него бы отреагировали, а значит, причин считать его неверным из-за отсутствия голосов нет.

Comment: Кошмар! Никакой свободы для художника слова.Вот Гоголь, например, взял и сжег второй том "Мертвых душ" и   разрешения ни у кого не стал спрашивать. Это тоже вандализм?